# SQL Express é gratuito?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin-forms, sql-server-express

Preciso de um banco de dados para usar num aplicativo Xamarin Forms para a faculdade. Cheguei a criar no Azure, porém a limitação de 32 MB é muito grande, pois preciso armazenar fotos também. Dei uma pesquisada e vi que tem a versão Express do SQL, que permite até 10GB no banco.

Essa informação procede? Alguma outra alternativa ou algum artigo para me guiar?

A aplicação tem que ser Xamarin Forms, mas não tem definição do banco a ser utilizado.

Comment: A limitação de 10 GiB da edição Express, a partir da versão 2008 R2, é por banco de dados. É possível utilizar mais de 10 GiB desde que crie vários bancos de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A informação procede e não faz a menor diferença onde vai usar, só é importante que a aplicação consiga acessar o banco de dados.

Mas parece que está querendo que a aplicação acesse o banco de dados diretamente, eu evitaria isso, pelo menos por questões de segurança.

A não ser que esteja falando de ter o banco de dados no mobile, aí deveria usar um SQLite ou algo semelhante, mas acho que não é isto.

Usar um banco de dados grátis não significa que terá infraestrutura grátis.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Os 10 GB são grátis? A questão de acessar diretamente você se refere a usar um Web Service?

Comment: São, mas você vai ter que hospedar isso em algum lugar que não é grátis. me refiro a ter uma aplicação que controle isso. Web Service é uma possibilidade, nem sempre a mais adequada.

Comment: Uma última dúvida de iniciante. Posso usar meu próprio pc como server inicialmente? Se sim, o que preciso fazer?

Comment: Poder pode, mas nem um experiente faria isto, um iniciante vai sofrer demais, pelo menos para algo em produção, para testes, ok.